# How can I write a command that checks for a named item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set up a contraption that will scan for a Ghast Tear called *"essence of chuck norris"*, but I can't seem to get the commands right.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Welcome to Arquade, Toasty. Please click the check mark next to answers you found helpfull to help other visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `/testfor` command:

```
/testfor <target> [NBT]
```

And in your case, it will look like this:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:minecraft:ghast_tear,tag:{display:{Name:"essence of chuck norris"}}}}
```

But watch out! The commands are case-senitive, watch out especially for capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will tag any player with the named ghast tear.  This tag can then be used to target those players for other commands.  Commands are for 1.12.2.

---

Use 2 command blocks in a chain.

The first command block is <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a remove Holding
```

The second command block is <kbd>Chain</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add Holding {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:ghast_tear",tag:{display:{Name:"essence of chuck norris"}}}]}
```

Now you can use this tag to target the players who currently have the item in their inventory.  An example command to kill them all would be:

```
kill @a[tag=Holding]
```